# How to resolve gradle conflicts in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, version

Please find my gradle file below.
[image: Gradle file]

As you can see its showing inn red.and if i place cursor there I get the hint as 'All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification.Found '

> 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0

and

> 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0 '

So i followed the hint and explicitly added

> com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0

' ,with the correct version ,as you can see in the image.Still its showing error.

Please help.

Comment: remove support-v4 implementation

Comment: which android version u can use ?

Comment: try to update version of all com.android.support to 27.0.2

Comment: just ignore the first red line error, if you delete first line it will show you in the second line, so ignore it. just use latest api version 27 and latest build tools version and latest support library version.

Comment: gradle prog is very sensitive ! you should go for! using 27.0.2 libs !! and make sure your compiler version and compile sdk versions are the same!
I happend to see that though android has new build tools and libs of 27.0.2 added but new project gets made up in 26 yet! but the above helped me too

Comment: try adding-  
   compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'

Comment: The hint is quite clear `26.1.0 != 27.1.0`

Comment: @PrafullaMalviya tried removing that.but still giving same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened sometimes when we use external libraries from `Github` and I have faced it many times. I can notice you are using some external libraries in project. These libraries might using version `27.1.0` and you are using `26.1.0`. Solution to this problem is either remove those libraries or change your version from `26.1.0 to 27.1.0`

and If you trying latest version, don't forgot to do following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Comment: I should manually change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 27 and all the dependencies version from 26.1.0 to 27.1.0 ? @Zaid Mirza

Comment: yes because it seems external libraries are using latest version for dependencies

Comment: @neab glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

> Support library should not use a different version than the
>   comileSdkVersion