# all android support libraries must use exact same version not working

Tags: android, gradle

Edit : i also this post

[All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

i upgrade downgrade multiple version of android support libraries . but i am constantly getting this error . specially on these lines

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
```

i clean and rebuild multiple times , but that is not solution

there is no specifically any solution which i got except changing library version .

this is app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codepath.the_town_kitchen"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("keystore/debug.keystore")
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')


    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    // ActiveAndroid for simple persistence with an ORM
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.3.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    //compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    // compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'

    //compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'

    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
    //compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
}
```

is there any particular by whoch android studio can automatically set version of all existing libraries ? 
i need some suggestions

Comment: please refer this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030498/how-to-resolve-gradle-conflicts-in-android-studio/49030661#49030661

Comment: U can gradle build in Offline mode ya online mode??

Comment: Offline mode I also tried . still not working

Answer (score 4):

> is there any particular by whoch android studio can automatically set
>   version of all existing libraries ?

Yes, android studio will automatically set version of all existing libraries by this code.
Put this at the end of your app module in build.gradle.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion '27.0.2'
        }
    }
}
```

This will find all support dependencies and force their versions to be 27.0.2. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex ............. this error started to come , thats very irritating issue

Comment: first of all try to clean your project and rebuilt it. Let me know if it works or not.@NeerajVerma

Comment: No still not working , can you share screen wid me and help me out when u are available

Comment: Yes, i can. i am not too good in it but i can try my best to solve your problem. i am not free now...so if you don't mind send me request on my fb ac... i will msg you when i will become free. 
My fb ac:- https://www.facebook.com/kalkani.jaydip.1

Comment: This causes the following error: **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected inputs: ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1, file=/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/35.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}**

Comment: I think you are adding it at wrong location. Insert this code in app level build.gradle file at end. @IgorGanapolsky

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this you need to update your **libs** too.

Your **libs** like **Picasso** also contain `'com.android.support'` library which need to be compatible with you *app* `'com.android.support'` library, And I can see you used old versions of library which contain old version of `'com.android.support'`.

You need to use *libs* that contain the compatible `'com.android.support'` version, In your case it's `27.0.2`

For example *Picasso* needed to upgrade to `2.5.2` instead.

Comment: yes , i agreed ,  i need to look at every 3rd party libraries , thats compatible with latest version

Comment: can all external libraries be updated automatically ?