# can't resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

when i implementation this [com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2] it show me that i have to upgrade to [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2] which will let me in end of way to upgrade all implementation any idea how to fix it?

```html
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.0.2, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and com.android.support:design:26.1.0 less
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)
```

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.smallville.concert"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve gradle conflicts in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030498/how-to-resolve-gradle-conflicts-in-android-studio)

Comment: did you solve it?